# Javascript: removeChild not working

Tags: javascript, removechild

Would you please help me?
Why isn't `removeChild` working in my code?

```
    divId = $(".File[rel='" + fileId.substring(0, 32) + "']");
    divId.parentNode.removeChild(divId);
```

(The first line is working, which can find the div)

Comment: jQuery objects are not `Node` objects. In order to use the methods from `Node` you need to extract the wrapped DOM element using `get()` or `[]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) for that:

```
divId = $(".File[rel='" + fileId.substring(0, 32) + "']");
divId.remove();
```

`$(selector)` returns a jQuery object which does not have a `parentNode` property. You can alternatively use [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) or array notation if you actually need to get a DOM element reference as answered by @dystroy.

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
divId = $(".File[rel='" + fileId.substring(0, 32) + "']");
```

to

```
divId = $(".File[rel='" + fileId.substring(0, 32) + "']").get(0);
```

or simply use jQuery's [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) function which takes care of the awkwardness of the DOM removeChild function :

```
divId.remove();
```

Comment: Or `$(".File[rel='" + fileId.substring(0, 32) + "']")[0]` instead of `.get(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

To acces the parent use:

```
divId.parent();
```

but you don't need the parent, you can just do:

```
divId.remove();
```